# Using thread unsafe values in an async block

Tags: multithreading, rust, future

In this code snippet ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c8dcb47b60fd39916cfb90c5f0f194c4)), we have some simple communication between two threads. The main thread (which executes the second `async` block) sends `2` to thread 2 in the `async move` block, which receives it, adds its own value, and sends the result back over another channel to the main thread, which prints the value.

Thread 2 contains some local state, the `thread_unsafe` variable, which is neither `Send` nor `Sync`, and is maintained across an `.await`. Therefore the `impl Future` object that we are creating is itself neither `Send` nor `Sync`, and hence the call to `pool.spawn_ok` is a compile error.

However, this seems like it should be fine. I understand why `spawn_ok()` can't accept a future that is not `Send`, and I also understand why the compilation of the async block into a state machine results in a struct that contains a non-`Send` value, but in this example the only thing I want to send to the other thread is `recv` and `send2`. How do I express that the future should switch to non-thread safe mode only after it has been sent?

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use futures::channel::oneshot::channel;
use futures::executor::{ThreadPool, block_on};

fn main() {
    let pool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();
    let (send, recv) = channel();
    let (send2, recv2) = channel();
    pool.spawn_ok(async move {
        let thread_unsafe = Rc::new(RefCell::new(40));
        let a = recv.await.unwrap();
        send2.send(a + *thread_unsafe.borrow()).unwrap();
    });
    let r = block_on(async {
        send.send(2).unwrap();
        recv2.await.unwrap()
    });
    println!("the answer is {}", r)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but in this example the only thing I want to send to the other thread is `recv` and `send2`

There is also the local variable `thread_unsafe` which is used across an `.await`. Since `.await` can suspend an async function, and later resume it on another thread, this could send `thread_unsafe` to a different thread, which is not allowed.

Comment: Is this a property of `spawn_ok` specifically? As in, is there an executor that will always execute tasks on the thread where they started, so that it can execute thread unsafe futures? I guess this can at least be expressed in the type system as a `Send` closure that returns a non-`Send` future to execute.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro It's a property of multithreaded executors. A single-threaded executor should be able to spawn and execute a non-`Send` future just fine.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Indeed, the [`smol::LocalExecutor`](https://docs.rs/async-executor/0.1.2/async_executor/struct.LocalExecutor.html#method.spawn) for example does not require the future to be `Send`.

Comment: @rodrigo But that executor is completely single threaded, right? Is there an executor that has a thread pool type setup, where jobs are assigned to individual threads but the jobs are not moved from their thread once started?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Take a loot at tokio's [`spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.22/tokio/task/fn.spawn_local.html) or async_std's [`spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.6.3/async_std/task/fn.spawn_local.html): multithreaded executor, but the task is pinned to the thread that created it.